# How to change canvas size for image using codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to dynamically-rotate a rectangular image using Codename1.  Although this works (using image rotate method), the image is clipped because the canvas size is not increased nor rotated to contain the new image orientation.

Is there a fast way to increase the canvas size of an image (and center the image) from within CN1?  Alternatively, can anyone think of another way to do this with an image that must be manipulated by the application?

My thoughts were: 1) Increase canvas size to be able to hold new dimensions of image, 2) Rotate the image using the rotate() method, (optional but also helpful) 3) Clip the wasted canvas space.

Efficient/fast is a must.

Thank you!

Comment: If I correctly understand the Image class, and the ability to obtain a graphics object from an image, I *think* I can do this by creating a "blank" image that is the "post-rotation" size, retrieving a Graphics object to it, and then drawing the original image on top of it.  Then the canvas should be large enough to contain the rotated image.  That's what I'm going to attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Working with mutable images isn't necessarily fast on all platforms so if this is something you want to do in runtime using the rotate() transform on `Graphics` might actually be faster.

What you seem to be looking for is `Image.rotate90Degrees(boolean)`, `Image.rotate180Degrees(boolean)`, `Image.rotate270Degrees(boolean)`.

These methods also change the dimensions of the image accordingly to the rotation and produce an encoded image of the result. They work thru moving the RGB values by default so its not necessarily the fastest method there is but if you are doing image manipulation it should be reasonable.